# Monotouch not generating .cs and .h files after editing in XCode IB

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, monodevelop, xamarin

I'm not sure if I'm missing something or my installation is broken or it's a bug.

The problem: following the storyboards tutorial:

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Introduction_to_Storyboards

doesn't work. The part where I'm supposed to close the IB and see generated .cs file in MonoDevelop doesn't happen.

I did this several different ways, restarted the computer per one source's suggestion, tried closing, quitting everything in every order per other suggestions.

What doesn't work is adding a new View Controller in IB and closing the storyboard should cause new .cs and .h files to be generated but they aren't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I missed the minute detail of assigning a Custom Class name for the view controllers.

Make sure you select the view controller in IB (not some view inside) and set the Custom Class (not Label) to a name you wish. Save and close IB, MonoTouch should now generate .cs file